# KeyError in pandas when trying to find max value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to find the max values of the wind speed, but I`m getting keyerror: "wind_speed"

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('wind.csv', delimiter=';')
#print(df.head(10))

p = df["wind_speed"].max()

print(p)
```

Comment: check the output of `df.columns` and check whether `wind_speed` is present or not or you misspelled it or not

Comment: @AnuragDabas `wind_speed` is present when checking the ouput `df.columns`

Comment: If there are not much columns in your dataframe then try considering adding the output of `df.columns` in your question